# ASP.NET Identity - where my tables created?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-membership

I have created sample register page to create user using ASP.NET Identity. Actually, I am working with this project since long back; which means, database is already existing.

From Register.aspx page, when clicked on the **Register** button, getting the message like "User created successfully"; but could not able to find out where relevant tables created.

Below is the connectionstrings section of my web.config file. Please note that, second connectionString "LocalDBConnectionString" is existing but NOT using anywhere, and in-fact not working.

I have verified with all the relevant databases for membership tables, but could not find relevant one.

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="ASHOKConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=SHRESTASOFT\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ASHOK;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa; Password=tentod" />
<add name="LocalDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ClassDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True" />
<add name="ASHOKEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityFramework.ASHOK.csdl|res://*/EntityFramework.ASHOK.ssdl|res://*/EntityFramework.ASHOK.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SHRESTASOFT\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=ASHOK;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=tentod;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="NORTHWINDDataContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityFramework.NorthwindDataContext.csdl|res://*/EntityFramework.NorthwindDataContext.ssdl|res://*/EntityFramework.NorthwindDataContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SHRESTASOFT\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=NORTHWND;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=tentod;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Where could the database be created?

**Update - One more help required**: Please observe that **ASHOKConnectionString** is existing inside connectionstrings section of web.config. This is the one I am using currently for other pages. If I want to get my ASP.NET Identity related tables into this database, how can I do? Can anybody please suggest me!

Answer (score 0):

You can find where the members are stored by looking the membership field on web.config. For example you have to see something like:

```
<roleManager ... >
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add connectionStringName="ASHOKConnectionString"   ... />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<membership  >
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add connectionStringName="ASHOKConnectionString" ... />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

and inside that database that is used for members, there are 11 tables that starts with `aspnet_` and there are your member.

Comment: thank you for your response. I have carefully verified all the sections in web.config, but coun't find above sections you have suggested.